# Don't move vote buttons past the bottom of the post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, user-interface

This is a request for a tweak in [Move the vote button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35041/move-the-vote-button) is currently in [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing).

The effect is visually jarring. On the other hand this serves a useful purpose — keep the score and the voting buttons visible when scrolling down to the bottom of a long post.

It doesn't make sense to have the buttons go further down than the bottom of the post itself though. Please stop at the bottom of the post, don't make the vote buttons go next to the comments or post notices.

Comment: I don't know about post notices. But sometimes (IMO), comments can enlighten you and it may also change your vote on the post (imagine that for a giant list of comments where one might induce something on your mind). Well, I don't have any difficulties with moving buttons getting near the comments section, nor do I see a good reason for constraining the buttons especially.

Comment: @Waffle'sCrazyPeanut If you're voting based on the comments, or changing your mind based on comments after you have already voted, then you're doing something wrong. And it's not *that* hard to scroll back up a bit either if you realize after the fact that you voted wrong.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: It's entirely possible that I might've overlooked something, and it has happened a lot of times - I don't know (nor do I see) everything in a particular answer. And, I didn't ask to implement the scheme of moving the buttons near the comments. I just said that there's no reason to constrain that nice scheme. *(Well, it's also not hard to ignore the moving buttons)*...

Comment: THANK YOU.  This was driving me absolutely insane, and making me wonder why my comment had 25 upvotes.  The initial change is somewhat useful for posts, but gets unwieldy the longer the comments section becomes.

Comment: [Downvote without comment notification doesn't show up properly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296130/downvote-without-comment-notification-doesnt-show-up-properly)

Comment: @davidkonrad et al **Please provide feedback to Jarrod ([on his answer below](/a/257914)**, not to me, I'm just another user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't move vote buttons past bottom of the text in a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257978/dont-move-vote-buttons-past-bottom-of-the-text-in-a-post)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pushing this change out now - the controls will stop at the bottom of a votable post and not descend into the comments.

Also, disabling the experiment on all sites except Stack Overflow, as that site is the only one with appropriate styling for post notices.

Comment: Sweet, was about to post a screenshot of one place it looked wonky.

Comment: Did you change the A/B group? I'm not seeing moving buttons anymore even on SO.

Comment: @Gilles the experiment is disabled for a bit, while the build goes out - should be back in 20 minutes or so.

Comment: @Gilles experiment is re-enabled on SO - good call on the movement limiting.

Comment: [Downvote without comment notification doesn't show up properly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296130/downvote-without-comment-notification-doesnt-show-up-properly)

Comment: @JarrodDixon All questions related to the experiment have been closed now, except for this one. This question is [tag:status-completed] so would it be appropriate to close this or not...?

Answer (score 13):

I agree. The voting is something that applies to the *post* not the *comments*.

There should also be a way to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen that the vote buttons will go through post notices if a post has one. This is definitely something that needs to be changed.

Comment: Yes, the experiment was to only run on Stack Overflow, which has styling changes to accommodate notices  - fixing that now.

Comment: @JarrodDixon I think it might be beneficial to run this on at least one or two smaller sites, or at least a few communities where, on the whole, users have different voting trends than SO to begin with (to help determine if this should be a network wide thing).

Comment: If the experiment **works,** it'll be available *everywhere*, @enderland. If we can't make it work on SO, then trying to even determine if it works elsewhere is gonna be hard. So... Cross fingers & be patient.

Comment: @Shog9 my point is more because I don't know how similar all sites user voting patterns are and how this might affect them differently (no access to secrit information). I _suspect_ that many sites have different "voter frequently" breakdowns than Stack Overflow, which may be impacted differently than SO would.  Though it wouldn't really make sense to have the voting buttons act differently on different SE sites... :)

Comment: @enderland Exactly; having such an important interface element behave differently would be disorienting. It's either everywhere or nowhere. And it makes sense to pick between two based on what's good for SO.