# Don't move vote buttons past bottom of the text in a post

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface

This is related to the previous feature of not [moving vote buttons past the bottom of the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257910/dont-move-vote-buttons-past-the-bottom-of-the-post).

I'd like to request that the "bottom" of a post be redefined to be the *bottom of the text* and not include the user card. On short posts, the user card introduces unnecessary scrolling.

---

For example:

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30667426/189134) is the smaller than the size of the vote/score buttons:

[image: Unscrolled Answer]

If, however, I scroll down to start reading the other answers, the buttons follow just enough to be distracted by the moving UI component. It follows to the bottom of the user card.

[image: Scrolled Answer]

Notice that the buttons on the above image followed me down to the "add comment" (just below the user card).

The stickiness is nice on long posts (like the question portion of the link above), but several of the answers are short and the stickiness is distracting when it occurs unnecessarily. I think this can be resolved by only keeping the buttons sticky within the size of the answer text and not including the user card.