# Sticky vote feature does not work when you load new answers

Tags: feature-request, voting

This is a request for a small tweak in the feature [Move the vote button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35041/move-the-vote-button) that is currently in [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) just for Stack Overflow.

When you are reading a new question and preparing to answer, someone else may be faster and answer it first. When you click to load his answer, the CSS class `js-vote-sticky` will not be added to the new answer and the vote button will not behave consistently.

<kbd>[image: sticky]</kbd>

Comment: @moderator, I've raised a flag to mark this question as [status-declined] [since it will not be implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please?lq=1).