# Why do all Stack Exchange sites not benefit from the same upgrades as others?

Tags: support

A few instances I've seen nice features introduced to particular Stack Exchange sites, but then others will be without them. I would've thought it's built upon a similar (if not the same) framework.

Example: The 'sticky' voting panels on SO which (I think!?) are new to a release today or yesterday, but meta doesn't seem to have it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sticky voting panels are [currently undergoing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35041/move-the-vote-button#comment840973_254795) [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) to see if they're beneficial. If they are, then they'll presumably be rolled out for all users on all sites.

While some sites have community-specific extensions (usually related to [how posts are rendered](https://stackapps.com/questions/6157/questions-body-rendering-in-androids-webview/6158#6158)), they generally all do have feature parity. Occasionally Meta (this site) will get new unique features that need to be vetted for bugs/polished, but after that feedback process has taken place they get deployed to the rest of the network.